# O(N) Sort Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Given an array of unsorted values of size 100 (the list has 100 elements), and 
each value is drawn randomly from the range of [0…1000] inclusive. Design an 
algorithm to sort the given list in a linear time (that is O(N) worst-case performance).

Hint: Make use of the fact that the range of the values is known in advance (i.e., from 1 to 1000)

This is one of the HW questions for my class. He wants pseudocode for a function that does the above. I just can't think of a function to do this that has O(N) worst-case performance.

P.S. - It isn't supposed to be anything complicated like Radix sort.
P.S.S - I just want help with an idea on how to do it. Not looking for someone to do my homework.

This is in java btw.

Thanks!

Comment: Your title says search, your question says sort. Please clarify.

Comment: May the numbers in the original array duplicate?

Comment: Homework questions are not very welcome here... Please add the homework tag at least...

Comment: check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: @alex-shesterov Homework is no longer an acceptable tag. My personal policy is to look at questions through the filter of how narrow or broad they are. Most homework questions are "too localized" and can safely be closed. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: Btw... +1 for a decent question.

Comment: @Barranka Correct me if I'm wrong, but Quicksort is a comparison sort, and thus limited to O(n lg n) lower bound.

Comment: Is N in your example 100 or 1000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is a [Counting Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). You track the number of times each number occurred, then simply print them back in order.

Comment: This is the best answer, and there is even pseudocode at the link given by Nick. Bitmap sort is the same thing, but more of a jargon name for counting sort.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [bitmap sort](http://designingefficientsoftware.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/bitmap-sort/). It works by using the set of unsorted values as indexes in an array, and runs in O(N) time.

Comment: Hmm. We haven't done anything nearly that complicated in class yet. I've never even used bitmaps before.

Comment: Not exactly, it just takes all the integers x in the unsorted set and sets `myary[x] = 1` where `myary` is an array of size 1000. To view the sorted set, just loop through the array and prints all the indexes of the array's elements that are set to 1.

Comment: Yup. It is O(N), even though it will take two iterations to get there.

Comment: Agreed, it's O(2N) but we ignore constant multipliers in O(N) notation - so, O(N) it is.

Comment: @ryanbwork, strictly speaking, doing this the way you describe does not allow for duplicate numbers. It can be easily edited to allow it, but then it is just a counting sort.

Answer (score 0):

Nick is correct (give him credit--I'm only answering because it wouldn't fit into the comment field).

You would define an array with 1,001 elements all initialized to zero. You read the 100 values one at a time, incrementing the array element which has the same index as the value that you are reading. After you do this 100 times, you will have an array of 1,001 elements (mostly still zero), and you simply print the number 0 as many times as specified by the value in the 0th array element, then the number 1 as many times as specified by the value in the 1st array element, etc. This sounds slow, but since it is an O(n) algorithm, it is faster than any other sorting method, but works only since you know the inputs are all integers within the range of 0 to 1,000 (1,001 total possibilities).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the "counting sort" would be O(n) + O(N) (where n = 100 & N = 1000).  But like all schemes that claim to be better than n log(n) it "cheats", because the O(N) component is in reality an N log N component when you take into account the cost of expanding memory -- memory performance is log N to memory size.  It's just that, for the particular processor in question, memory size is fixed and hence the log N factor is buried.

Comment: You're right, of course. It is proven (and you can read 200-page books about it at the library) that O(n log n) is the best possible bound for solving the unconstrained sorting problem. This one is a constrained sorting problem, though, and the big-O notation is unaffected by constant factors and lower-order terms, so it is indeed O(n). The OP needs to please the teacher, and the teacher would be expecting something along the lines of counting sort.

Comment: If you want to use that argument, you must count the time it takes to compare elements in your comparison sort.  A comparison sort performs O(n log n) comparisons, each of which takes O(log n) time to access the element to compare and O(log N) time to actually compare.  So a comparison sort is O(n log n log max(n,N)).

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the algorithm they teach for this in your first algorithms class: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Answer (score 0):

The cost of counting sort in this case seems to be O(N+Nsqrt(N))=O(N^3/2). I think this can be improved using the radix_sort as @Daniel_Williams told us. See for instance Lecture 5 of the MIT Open Course https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VqawRl3Xzs